# How to have a separated js file that handles the API calls in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, service

I want to structure my react project and set my `API`s and methods that makes the calls in a separate file. I am coming from Angular background, in Angular there are services which handle all `http` calls.

So, assume that i have a `functional component` called `Supplier` that have two files, `Supplier.js` and `Supplier.css`. I want to add a new file and call it `SupplierServices.js` in this file i want to write all methods that makes the calls to the server and simply import it in `Supplier.js`.

how to achieve this?

Comment: The same as you described. Create different file, put there your methods and then import them in your component.

Comment: @demkovych I tried it in different ways but it never worked, can you please answer it, how the methods in the file should look like and how to import this file in `Supplier.js`

Comment: You can Use a  state manager for that. Put all your methods and http calls in your state, and then use it in any file in your app. If you're not building a big project, I'd recommend you use context for the management.

Comment: @SiradjiAwoual so are you saying to create a new component and store the mehtods in the `state` then import this component in other components ?

Comment: I see that getting into state management will be a bit fast for you, so i decide to use a different approach. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file with **request.js**:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default () => axios.get('/test');
```

Your component **component.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import {request} from './request';

const Component = () => {
  .....
  request();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Components are just functions. You don't necesarily need to render anything in them, they can hold logic or API calls if you want. Before [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), and when working without a state manager like Redux, you usually saw either [HOCs (higher order components)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) or [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) be used to compose logic together, here are some examples:

[Using HOCs](https://medium.com/@guigonc/refactoring-moving-api-calls-to-a-higher-order-component-53062c086cb)

[Using hooks and render props](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/data-fetcher-component-using-hooks-and-render-props-aacf3162dfc2)

[You can use hooks alone as well](https://blog.bitsrc.io/making-api-calls-with-react-hooks-748ebfc7de8c)

There's also nothing stopping you from 'emulating' services like in your example, it's mostly a matter of taste and being aware of the pros and cons of each method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this
1. Create the method you want to export inside suppliers devices.js.

```
 SupplierServices.js
 Export const fetchData =  async () => {
 Const res =   await axios.get(your url) 
 Console.log(res) 
 }
```

2. Now import the fetchData method from supplierServices

```
Import { fetchData } from './SupplierServices'
Const Supplier = () => { 
 useEffect(.() =>{ 
 fetchData ()
 } )
}
```

Comment: but what if i need to post data? in the `Supplier.js` there is a form where on submit i need to call a function that is defined in `SupplierServices.js`

Comment: You can do it all the same. <Form onSubmit={postData()} >. But honestly, it's best for you to use state manger for this.

Answer (score 0):

i used to use **[flux architecture](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-the-flux-architectural-pattern-674ea74775c9/)** - this pattern can be use in every framework.

[More info about implementing redux](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-redux-in-reactjs-with-real-life-examples-687ab4441b85/)

```
   └─ client
      └─ redux
         └─ services
         └─ actions
         └─ reducers
```

Later encapsulating logic parts into individual parts (user.service, event.service, transaction service) etc.

---

Usually, event calls actions, which call service (in service promisses are operated asynchronously - try-catch), which return data(success) or error - that call the reducer and change the application's UI state (a bit complexity - but the advantage is the possibility of management all components - regardless of their relationality (global status).